# How do I describe the following system?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, frequency, oscillators, resonance

So the professor of my physics 3 class assigned this problem regarding forced oscillations.

[image: Driven pendulum] A mass of 0.30kg hangs of a massless rope. The center of oscillation can move as shown in the figure. When the driving frequency $\omega$ is zero, the pendulum oscillates 100 times before its amplitude is about 35% of the initial amplitude.

1. Write an equation that describes the system in the presence of external forces.
2. Find the solution and determine the resonance frequency, the quality factor $Q$, the maximum amplitude, and the phase as a function of the driving frequency.

The thing is I have no idea how to start. I tried describing the system in terms of angular position, but I just don't see how I'm supposed to take the periodic displacement $\mu(t)$ into account. A hint and a brief explanation would be highly appreciated.

Comment: For clarification purposes, I don't want the problem to be solved. I only need to know how I'm supposed to take the driving force into account. I'm don't really get what type of coordinate system I should use.

Comment: I can't be sure - it is many years since I did questions on this topic, and I never did many. I would use Cartesian coordinates because otherwise the angle between rod and axis only accasionally coincides with the coordinate angle of the bob. The information you are given about decay when $\omega=0$ doesn't mention amplitude, so you might be able to use the approximation that $sin\theta \approx \theta$ to analyse that part. Beyond that I don't know without starting the problem myself.

Comment: "The thing is I have no idea how to start." - Usually you start with the kinematics of the a problem and then apply the equations of motion.

Comment: @JAlex I guess I should've expressed the situation differently, my bad. What I meant is that I get lost at choosing a coordinate system. The most natural way of describing this system is through $\theta$, and I don't know how I'm supposed to put $\mu(t)$ in the equation of motion of the system since it's described along the x-direction in cartesian coordinates. Anyway, Saym's answers gave me a clue, which is what I asked for.

Comment: @Shadow3456TB - both $\theta$ and $\mu$ are degrees of freedom and they go into the equations of motion via the kinematics of the center of mass. See my answer on how this is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can start off with just the pendulum.

Info #1: length and mass of object given. Natural frequnecy ($\omega_0$) of the free pendulum can be found out.
Info #2: when $\omega = 0$ ,  from this frictional coefficient of the oscillatory system can be found out.
Now, if the top of the pendulum is undergoing an acceleration(like in a car maybe) then we see that the pendulum starts to move(pseudo-acceleration).

So the instataneous acceleration is $\frac{d^2\mu}{dt^2}$.
Now, you can make an assumption that is the oscillations are very small, then you will notice that the pendulum's motion in y direction is negligible.
Thus,
$$(\frac{d^2}{dt^2} + \omega_0^2 + \beta \frac{d}{dt})x(t) = m \frac{d^2\mu}{dt^2}$$

To make this in $\theta$, you can use $x = lsin(\theta)$.. and for small $\theta$, $x = lsin(\theta) \approx  l\theta$

Answer (score 0):

First you need to track the center of mass of the object in position, velocity and acceleration.

Use the chain rule from calculus to differentiate with time.

### Position

$$ \begin{aligned} 
  x & = \mu + \ell \sin \theta \\
  y & = - \ell \cos \theta \\
\end{aligned} $$

### Velocity

$$ \begin{aligned} 
  \dot{x} & = \dot{\mu} + \ell \dot{\theta} \cos \theta \\
  \dot{y} & = \ell \dot{\theta} \sin \theta \\
\end{aligned} $$

### Acceleration

$$ \begin{aligned} 
  \ddot{x} & = \ddot{\mu} - \ell \dot{\theta}^2 \sin \theta + \ell \ddot{\theta} \cos \theta \\
  \ddot{y} & = \ell \dot{\theta}^2 \cos \theta + \ell \ddot{\theta} \sin \theta  \\
\end{aligned} $$

### Equations of Motion

Do a free body diagram and add the forces on the object to develop the equations of motion

$$ \begin{aligned}
  \sum F_x & = m \ddot{x} \\
  \sum F_y & = m \ddot{y} 
\end{aligned} $$

### Solution

Since you know the displacement profile $\mu(t)$, you know it's derivatives (namely $\ddot{\mu}$). Use that in the equations of motion to answer your questions.